# ksoap in android with .net

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

am trying to connect to a web service in order to retrieve some data with an android device with ksoap2.  i assume that i have make the configuration correct and the result that i get back from the web service is **anyType{}**  the code that i use is the below

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/" ;
private static final String URL = "http://IP/CardiacPortalWS/VitalInfoWS.asmx";
private static final String HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getPatient";
private static final String METHOD_NAME1 = "getPatient";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

    request.addProperty("patientID",8);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
    SoapObject receivedString=null;
    try
    {
       androidHttpTransport.call(HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       receivedString = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
       Log.v("Server", "server data1 "+receivedString.getPropertyCount());
       Log.i("Server", "server data2 "+receivedString.getProperty(0));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { }
```

The SOAP file is

SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/getPatient"

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getPatient xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <patientID>int</patientID>
      <name>string</name>
      <SID>string</SID>
      <sex>boolean</sex>
      <birthday>dateTime</birthday>
      <nationality>string</nationality>
      <telephone>string</telephone>
      <telephone1>string</telephone1>
      <email>string</email>
      <maritalStatusName>string</maritalStatusName>
      <educationName>string</educationName>
      <ejectionFraction>int</ejectionFraction>
      <profession>string</profession>
      <deathDateTime>dateTime</deathDateTime>
      <deathReason>string</deathReason>
      <isDead>boolean</isDead>
    </getPatient>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getPatientResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getPatientResult>
        <message>string</message>
        <code>int</code>
      </getPatientResult>
      <name>string</name>
      <SID>string</SID>
      <sex>boolean</sex>
      <birthday>dateTime</birthday>
      <nationality>string</nationality>
      <telephone>string</telephone>
      <telephone1>string</telephone1>
      <email>string</email>
      <maritalStatusName>string</maritalStatusName>
      <educationName>string</educationName>
      <ejectionFraction>int</ejectionFraction>
      <profession>string</profession>
      <deathDateTime>dateTime</deathDateTime>
      <deathReason>string</deathReason>
      <isDead>boolean</isDead>
    </getPatientResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i assume that the problem is in this line **request.addProperty("patientID",8);** but am not sure.  data on the server exist because am able to see them.
i would appreciate some help, an idea or a more detail tutorial

Comment: my problem is that am not getting any results.if i write spelling wrong the patientID or i if i write wrong id number my result is: anyType{message=Patient ID does not exist; code=-1; }   which i think until this point i goes on the getPatient xml and find the correct results.  when i add correct informations on the fields pathientID the result that i get is: anyType{message=anyType{}; code=0; }

Comment: This error is returned by webSevice means there is some error on server side . And also check once which parameter are optional(not null)

Comment: you mean on server and not on my code?  the webservice is in .net if make any point on all this?

Comment: is ur webservice on public ip ? And yes is this .net error not android , (might be caused by sending wrong input)

Comment: ok. thats mean that am sending the input in a wrong form. if i provide you the xml could you please help me to understand the correct form that i must send the inputs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6636/discussion-between-mohit-sharma-and-prokopis)

Comment: am trying to add two values on the database and the result code that am getting is _Undefined. it's mean that am trying to pass w=sommething wrong to the server ??????

Comment: @Mohit thanks for the help. the problem where the values that i add on the parameters. lets hope that i want find any problem with the other methods on the web service

Comment: Enjoyed helping u ... share correct code :)

Comment: am adding a new question ubon the ksoap that if the web service xml is in this form how am able to get the value price    'code'  <getOxygenSaturationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getOxygenSaturationResult>
        <message>string</message>
        <code>int</code>
      </getOxygenSaturationResult>
      <value>int</value>
    </getOxygenSaturationResponse>'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/" ;
private static final String URL = " http://IP/CardiacPortalWS/VitalInfoWS.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/userLogin";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "userLogin";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("PatientID", "10");
        request.addProperty("Weight", "72");
        String currentDateTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").
            format(new Date());
        request.addProperty("DateTimeStamp",currentDateTimeString);//"2012-01-13");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.i("Server", "server data2 "+((Object)envelope.getResponse()));  
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Server", "Error on server "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your mistake also

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think your webservice is returning a complex object (Patient), but you are treating it as a string. In that case, you need to have an Patient object that implements KvmSerializable Interface in order to receive the response. Take a look at this: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

What is the method signature of getPatient?